# Read bytes from min and max hex offsets with C#

Tags: c#, encoding, hex

I want to be able to read bytes from a min and max hexadecimal offset that is given through 2 strings string minO and string maxO. After that I just need to convert the bytes to a string.

```
//Setup byte reader.
FileStream fs = new FileStream(EditOpen.FileName, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
long length = fs.Length;
//Read bytes to textBox1.
string minO = 0x00001844;
string maxO = ???
br.BaseStream.Position = minO;
byte[] example = br.ReadBytes(0x000003FC);
textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(example);
```

0x00001844 is the min value and 0x00001C3F is the max value and 0x000003FC is the difference in hex.

This is the output:

```
73-20-67-6C-61-73-73-5F-62-72-65-61-6B-20-22-30-22-2E-2E-00-73-20-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-20-73-20-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-73-20-70-65-72-6B-5F-65-78-74-72-61-42-72-65-61-74-68-20-22-39-39-39-22-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-00-73-20-6D-6F-74-69-6F-6E-54-72-61-63-6B-65-72-52-61-6E-67-65-20-22-39-39-39-39-22-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-00-00-00-73-20-6C-6F-62-62-79-5F-61-6E-69-6D-61-74-69-6F-6E-53-70-65-65-64-20-22-36-30-22-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-00-00-73-20-67-6C-61-73-73-5F-73-68-61-74-74-65-72-65-64-5F-73-63-61-6C-65-20-22-30-22-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-00-00-73-20-67-6C-61-73-73-5F-66-72-69-6E-67-65-5F-6D-61-78-73-69-7A-65-20-22-31-30-30-22-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-2E-00-73-20-75-69-5F-67-61-6D-65-74-79-70-65-20-22-73-64-22-00-00-73-20-67-5F-67-61-6D-65-74-79-70-65-20-22-73-64-22-00-00-00-73-20-70-61-72-74-79-5F-67-61-6D-65-74-79-70-65-20-22-73-64-22-00-00-00-73-20-67-61-6D-65-74-79-70-65-20-22-22-00-00-00-6D-61-70-6E-61-6D-65-00-56-41-5F-46-4F-52-57-41-52-44-00-00-73-20-61-63-74-69-76-65-61-63-74-69-6F-6E-20-22-70-65-72-6B-5F-62-75-6C-6C-65-74-50-65-6E-65-74-72-61-74-69-6F-6E-4D-75-6C-74-69-70-6C-69-65-72-20-33-30-3B-70-65-72-6B-5F-64-69-76-65-47-72-61-76-69-74-79-53-63-61-6C-65-20-2E-30-31-3B-70-65-72-6B-5F-64-69-76-65-56-65-6C-6F-63-69-74-79-20-30-3B-70-65-72-6B-5F-64-69-76-65-44-69-73-74-61-6E-63-65-43-68-65-63-6B-20-39-39-39-3B-70-65-72-6B-5F-65-78-74-65-6E-64-65-64-4D-65-6C-65-65-52-61-6E-67-65-20-39-39-39-3B-70-65-72-6B-5F-67-72-65-6E-61-64-65-44-65-61-74-68-20-61-63-31-33-30-5F-31-30-35-6D-6D-5F-6D-70-3B-70-65-72-6B-5F-77-65-61-70-52-61-74-65-4D-75-6C-74-69-70-6C-69-65-72-20-2E-30-31-3B-63-67-5F-67-75-6E-5F-78-20-36-3B-67-6C-61-73-73-5F-66-72-69-6E-67-65-5F-6D-61-78-63-6F-76-65-72-61-67-65-20-31-30-30-30-30-30-30-3B-6D-6F-74-64-20-5E-31-47-65-74-5E-35-53-68-69-69-74-5E-37-4F-6E-5E-31-4B-69-64-73-20-20-20-5E-39-42-79-20-5E-32-42-55-53-54-45-44-5E-33-54-57-49-4E-4B-49-45-20-20-5E-34-40-7B-3D-33-5E-32-3C-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-5E-31-4A-4F-49-4E-20-5E-35-77-77-77-2E-58-62-6F-78-5E-37-33-36-30-5E-31-44-65-76-65-6C-6F-70-65-72-73-2E-5E-35-63-6F-6D-5E-32-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-3D-38-3B-70-65-72-6B-5F-73-70-72-69-6E-74-4D-75-6C-74-69-70-6C-69-65-72-20-35-3B-70-6C-61-79-65-72-5F-6C-61-73-74-53-74-61-6E-64-43-72-61-77-6C-53-70-65-65-64-53-63-61-6C-65-20-32-3B-70-6C-61-79-65-72-2B-73-70-72-69-6E-74-54-69-6D-65-20-39-39-39
```

I would like to have the output as plain text instead of hex. How can I do this?

Comment: good luck with that! Might want to add some code so we can actually help you with a problem you are having.

Comment: your question is not clear. First, you mention maxO and minO, but variables with those names are missing from your code. Also, you say you "need to convert the bytes to a **string**" but then you also say "I want binary".  What, exactly, is the desired output of this function?  String? binary?  What is meant by "binary" anyway?  Is this homework?  if so, it may clarify if you post the full question. Failing that, some example of an output.

Comment: No this is not homework here let me add maxO and minO

Comment: minO is easy to add but I don't know how to add maxO, I only know how to add the amount of bytes to load from minO.

Comment: Just added the output it gives but what I need is that output in plaintext without the -'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Binary or Hexadecimal output:**

You can use `Convert.ToString(byte, base)` to convert a byte to a hex string without any separators. Base can be 2 for binary or 16 for hexadecimal.

Use this in a for loop to convert all bytes:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(byte b in example)
{
    builder.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16).PadLeft(2,'0'));
}
textBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
```

**Plain text encoding:**

If you want to have plain text, you have to know the encoding of the file. For UTF8 you would use:

```
textBox1.Text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(example);
```

Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: I made a mistake by saying binary I meant plaintext.

Comment: There was a small mistake, you have to add PadLeft, so that it writes always 2 characters, prepending a zero if necessary. See the updated code.

Comment: Or if you mean normal text, use System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(example)

Comment: Now it just needs to be converted to plaintext.

Comment: i think the section about "plain text decoding" i added might be what you need.

Comment: That would cause an issue because the output of the builder isn't example it is builder.ToString(); wouldn't it have to decode the builders output not the initial string (example)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the comment. If you use the plain text encoding, you don't need any of the other code. Just the one line (without any StringBuilder).

Comment: It just outputs 19 bytes (I wonder why?) but at least in the right format.

Comment: You have zero bytes (0x00) in your file. the textbox will stop displaying text when it encounters a zero byte. May I ask what exactly you want to display the text for? It doesn't seem to be human readable really...

Comment: How can I display even the 00's then?

Comment: there is no display character to represent 0x00, you can choose another character or string, like: textBox1.Text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(example).Replace("\0", "[ZERO]")

Comment: This will replace all 00 with the string "[ZERO]"

Comment: Ok I will try that, I knew I would have to use replace XD

Comment: It worked and I have exactly what I want. Thanks alot for going out of your way to help me I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly, you want to have binary values instead of hex? You may code this in following way:

```
var bytes = br.ReadBytes(0x000003FC)
    .Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2));
```

And then use String.Join to concat strings as you want. For example:

```
textBox1.Text = String.Join(" ", bytes);
```

To get plain text, ofc, you should use Encoding. In case of UTF8:

```
textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(example);
```

Comment: Exactly did you see the output that it is currently giving me? That output needs to be plain text.